# How can i generate pdf reports using python?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pdf

Hi my requirement is extract data from excel and generate pdf using python? I read data from excel using python xlrd. Now i want to generate pdf report using that data.

I googled for this i get pod, pyjasper and reportlab.Among these which one is good.Is there another tool for generate pdf reports in python.

Please give me any suggestions..